# Excel Add-In keeps getting 401 error when trying to access Dynamics 365 Web Api

Tags: reactjs, excel, azure-active-directory, add-in, msal.js

I am trying to develop a word add in in React with Typescript that allows me to access the dynamics 365 Web Api.  The best example I've actually found was in a sample excel add in that accesses the graph api using MSAL 2.0 here https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-OfficeAddins/tree/master/Samples/auth/Office-Add-in-Microsoft-Graph-React.  If I can get a successful get request to my Dynamics 365 api after modifying the example code I will port the code over to my Word Add in.

However I keep getting a 401 error when trying to go to https://saltrial.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/
I get a response back when I simply paste this in a browser, but inside the add in I get 401 unauthorized.  I also get 401 unauthorized when I paste the token received from the add in into postman with the header of Bearer + token.   I have gotten a successful Access token however when I selected

[image]

I will show you my setup in Azure AD....  I have a client secret setup, but am not using it in my add in code.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Manifest
{
"id": "35c3a758-0edb-45f6-a97d-9c7180decd73",
"acceptMappedClaims": null,
"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
"addIns": [],
"allowPublicClient": true,
"appId": "4f7xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx310bf0",
"appRoles": [],
"oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
"createdDateTime": "2021-01-24T07:09:12Z",
"disabledByMicrosoftStatus": null,
"groupMembershipClaims": null,
"identifierUris": [
"api://localhost:3000/4fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
],
"informationalUrls": {
"termsOfService": null,
"support": null,
"privacy": null,
"marketing": null
},
"keyCredentials": [],
"knownClientApplications": [],
"logoUrl": null,
"logoutUrl": null,
"name": "TrySSO",
"oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": true,
"oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,
"oauth2Permissions": [
{
"adminConsentDescription": "Enable Office to call the add-in's web APIs with the same rights as the current user.",
"adminConsentDisplayName": "Office can act as the user",
"id": "5b3a4e4a-e55e-45ba-820b-ea16efbe3d5f",
"isEnabled": true,
"lang": null,
"origin": "Application",
"type": "User",
"userConsentDescription": "Enable Office to call the add-in's web APIs with the same rights that you have.",
"userConsentDisplayName": "Office can act as you",
"value": "access_as_user"
}
],
"oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
"optionalClaims": null,
"orgRestrictions": [],
"parentalControlSettings": {
"countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
"legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
},
"passwordCredentials": [
{
"customKeyIdentifier": null,
"endDate": "2299-12-31T05:00:00Z",
"keyId": "570axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxbcd1",
"startDate": "2021-01-28T04:11:05.086Z",
"value": null,
"createdOn": "2021-01-28T04:11:06.027737Z",
"hint": "mm-",
"displayName": "wordaddinsecret"
}
],
"preAuthorizedApplications": [
{
"appId": "ea5a67f6-b6f3-4338-b240-c655ddc3cc8e",
"permissionIds": [
"5b3a4e4a-e55e-45ba-820b-ea16efbe3d5f"
]
},
{
"appId": "d3590ed6-52b3-4102-aeff-aad2292ab01c",
"permissionIds": [
"5b3a4e4a-e55e-45ba-820b-ea16efbe3d5f"
]
},
{
"appId": "57fb890c-0dab-4253-a5e0-7188c88b2bb4",
"permissionIds": [
"5b3a4e4a-e55e-45ba-820b-ea16efbe3d5f"
]
},
{
"appId": "bc59ab01-8403-45c6-8796-ac3ef710b3e3",
"permissionIds": [
"5b3a4e4a-e55e-45ba-820b-ea16efbe3d5f"
]
}
],
"publisherDomain": "salnewtrial.onmicrosoft.com",
"replyUrlsWithType": [
{
"url": "https://localhost:3000/login/login.html",
"type": "Spa"
},
{
"url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient",
"type": "InstalledClient"
},
{
"url": "https://localhost:3000/login.html",
"type": "Web"
}
],
"requiredResourceAccess": [
{
"resourceAppId": "00000007-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
"resourceAccess": [
{
"id": "78ce3f0f-a1ce-49c2-8cde-64b5c0896db4",
"type": "Scope"
}
]
},
{
"resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
"resourceAccess": [
{
"id": "14dad69e-099b-42c9-810b-d002981feec1",
"type": "Scope"
},
{
"id": "7427e0e9-2fba-42fe-b0c0-848c9e6a8182",
"type": "Scope"
},
{
"id": "37f7f235-527c-4136-accd-4a02d197296e",
"type": "Scope"
},
{
"id": "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d",
"type": "Scope"
}
]
}
],
"samlMetadataUrl": null,
"signInUrl": null,
"signInAudience": "AzureADMyOrg",
"tags": [],
"tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
}

Inside my login.ts in excel add in

```
  (() => {
  // The initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded
  Office.initialize = () => {
    const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication({
      auth: {
        clientId: "4f7f40ec-xxxxxxxxx-5d6b18310bf0",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/cd77a053-xxxxxxxxxx3402c0fd62",  *This is tenant id
        redirectUri: "https://localhost:3000/login/login.html", // Must be registered as "spa" type
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage", // needed to avoid "login required" error
        storeAuthStateInCookie: true, // recommended to avoid certain IE/Edge issues
      },
    });

    // handleRedirectPromise should be invoked on every page load
    msalInstance
      .handleRedirectPromise()
      .then((response) => {
        // If response is non-null, it means page is returning from AAD with a successful response
        if (response) {
          Office.context.ui.messageParent(
            JSON.stringify({ status: "success", result: response.accessToken })
          );
        } else {
          // Otherwise, invoke login
          msalInstance.loginRedirect({
            scopes: [
              "user.read",
              "files.read.all",
              "https://saltrial.crm.dynamics.com//user_impersonation",
            ],
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorData: string = `errorMessage: ${error.errorCode}
                                   message: ${error.errorMessage}
                                   errorCode: ${error.stack}`;
        Office.context.ui.messageParent(
          JSON.stringify({ status: "failure", result: errorData })
        );
      });
  };
})();
```

Here is my API Call in Add in

```
    import axios from 'axios';

export const getGraphData = async (url: string, accesstoken: string) => {
    const response = await axios({
        url: url,
        method: 'get',
        headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${accesstoken}`,
        'OData-MaxVersion': '4.0',
        'OData-Version': '4.0',
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       }
      });
    return response;
};
```

Code that calls my api function and passes the scopes and dynamics url.  I console log the access token and put it into postman with header Bearer token, I get 401.  Also the add-in displays 401 unauthorized in the task pane....Ignore any naming of functions referring to the graph api, I'm hitting the dynamics 365 api and hoping I don't get the 401 error.  Thanks.

```
getFileNames = async () => {
    this.setState({ fileFetch: "fetchInProcess" });
    getGraphData(
      // Get the `name` property of the first 3 Excel workbooks in the user's OneDrive.
      "https://saltrial.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/WhoAmI",
      this.accessToken
    )
      .then(async (response) => {
        await writeFileNamesToWorksheet(response, this.displayError);
        this.setState({ fileFetch: "fetched", headerMessage: "Success" });
      })
      .catch((requestError) => {
        // If this runs, then the `then` method did not run, so this error must be
        // from the Axios request in getGraphData, not the Office.js in
        // writeFileNamesToWorksheet
        console.log("Access Token >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ", this.accessToken);
        this.displayError(requestError);
      });
  };
```

Comment: I notice that you put `"user.read", "files.read.all", "https://saltrial.crm.dynamics.com//user_impersonation"` in `scopes`. But the first 2 permission is under Microsoft Graph and the last one is for crm. I guess the access token is for Microsoft Graph rather than CRM. Please decode your access token in https://jwt.io to see what the `aud` claim is.

Comment: @AllenWu, I got it to work, I ditched the scopes for Graph, used a scope of /.default, and updated the headers.

Comment: Glad to know that. Would you like to post your solution as an answer to help others who may have the same issue?

Comment: @AllenWu When I get some time I'll post an answer.